# ASP.Net Core Publish failed due to Unable to copy the file

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, azure-webjobs

i'm trying to publish a webjob to Azure but I get some errors like the following. looks like it's because in the path after 'Out' it adds two backslashes instead of one (PubTmp\Out\\app_data).

```
28>Could not copy "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService.runtimeconfig.json" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService.runtimeconfig.json". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService.runtimeconfig.json'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Users\mohsen.rezaei\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration\4.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Users\mohsen.rezaei\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariables\3.1.6\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Users\mohsen.rezaei\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.1.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Users\mohsen.rezaei\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options.configurationextensions\3.1.6\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Users\mohsen.rezaei\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.8.1\runtimes\unix\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\runtimes\unix\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\runtimes\unix\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService.runtimeconfig.json" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService.runtimeconfig.json". Beginning retry 2 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService.runtimeconfig.json'. 
28>Could not copy "C:\Users\mohsen.rezaei\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration\4.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll" to "C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll". Beginning retry 2 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Development\TNG\ActivationService\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\PubTmp\Out\\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\TNG.Services.WindowsService.ActivationService\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.dll'. 
Further technical details
```

I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1 and visual studio 2019

Comment: In my case, the issue was that the project path was too long. It seems that there is a limitation of 256 characters. It worked with the 'Debug' profile but not with 'Release' profile, so I shortened the project path to be under 256 characters, and now it works.

Answer (score 6):

Could be that the publish path is too long.

Here are the steps which I did:

1. Rename your project (make it shorter).
2. Fix the dependencies in other projects if they are referencing your renamed project.
3. Rename containing project folder.
4. Remove the project from the solution and add it again (also to fix references).
5. Delete publish profile.
6. Clean and rebuild.
7. Create a new publish profile.

If it doesn't help - could be that the tour path is still too long.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, everything was working and without changing anything, I was getting the same error when trying to publish a webjob from visual studio.

I solved it by changing the Target Framework to .Net 5.0 instead of Net Core 3.1.

These are the steps I followed to fix the problem:

1. Right click on the project, then select .NET 5.0 in the target framework drop down.
2. Clean the project
3. Close visual studio
4. Delete manually the folders obj and bin
5. Open visual studio
6. Right click on the project and select Rebuild

When everything compiles successfully, try to publish again - it should work.

**If your dependencies are not yet compatible with .NET 5.0, I suggest you to downgrade to net core 2.0 (By following steps above) and then change it back to net core 3.1 (By following steps above).**

I have no idea why it happened, but at least that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the output with `-o`. For example using `dotnet publish -c Release -o dist`  to a local directory should prevent any need to rename anything to shorten paths.